# How to keep checkbox to stay checked after post function

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, post, checkbox, checked

my checkbox return false value after do a post action in codeigniter javascript.

**Here is my code for function subjectid_change:**

```
function subjectid_change(id, subjectid){
    setValue(id, subjectid);
    var field = '#ch' + id;
    set_credithour(field, subjectid);
}

$("select[name^=subjectid]").change(function(){
var subjectid = $(this).val();
set_credithour($(this).parent('td').find('input'), subjectid);
$(this).parent().find('input').attr('name', 'credithour['+subjectid+']');
$(this).parent().next()find('input').attr('name', 'gradepoint['+subjectid+']');
$(this).parent().next().next().find('input').attr('name', 'cgpacalc['+subjectid+']');
});
```

I have tried `e.preventDefault();` but it prevent me for changing the previous value.
I also tried using `.prop("checked")` and the result still same.

**This code for function subjectid_change:**

```
function set_credithour(field, subjectid){
    $.post('<?php echo site_url('academic/ajax_get_subject_credit'); ?>', {subjectid:subjectid}, 
    function(response){
        if(response.success){
          $(field).val(response.value);
        } else{
          alert('The subject you entered has no credit hour.');
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

So, what should I do if I want to keep checkbox to checked after do a `$.post`.

**In controller:**

```
function ajax_get_subject_credit()
{
    $subjectid = $this->input->post('subjectid');
    $this->db->select('subjectid, subjectcredit');
    $this->db->where('subjectid',$subjectid);
    $query = $this->db->get('ref_subject');
    $credithour = $query->row()->subjectcredit;
    $query->free_result();
    $result = $credithour;
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'value' => $result));

}
```

When I choose a subject, credit hour will auto-populate and click a checkbox to agree calculate the CGPA. But when I click Calculate button after add new subject, the calculation process not run and checkbox return to false. So, I've to click the checkbox again and Calculate button to make the process work. This make user do a same job twice. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the full code and show a demo?

Comment: You seem to be using javascript? Your post data is in your PHP code, and to determine if the checkbox was checked or not you will need to access the post data using php.

Comment: Ok, I see, so your doing an AJAX post... what data does it return? You may need to post your `ajax_get_subject_credit` function too.

Comment: I put some flow on my code.

Comment: You can't set a checkbox as checked using `.val()`. If your using jquery > 1.6, you could do something like `$(field).prop('checked', true);`

Comment: posting your \html code wile be better and easy for us to know what you are actually tryin to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my result:

I have spotted there is some error after post which is checkbox auto rename to gradepoint instead of cgpacalc.

```
var subjectid = $(this).val();
    set_credithour($(this).parent('td').next().find('input'), subjectid);
    $(this).parent().find('input[name^=subjectstudentid]').attr('name', 'subjectstudentid['+subjectid+']');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name^=credithour]').attr('name', 'credithour['+subjectid+']');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name^=gradepoint]').attr('name', 'gradepoint['+subjectid+']');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name^=cgpacalc]').attr('name', 'cgpacalc['+subjectid+']');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $.post('url',function(){
    $('checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    /*here go on with all your stuffs*/

    });
```

Comment: I've tried this method but the checkbox keep unchecked after do a post process

Comment: really strange is there any js binded to that checkbox before you call the post request?

Comment: Can I post checkbox value to post function using initial statement? If can, how to put checkbox value into `$.post('<?php echo site_url('academic/ajax_get_subject_credit'); ?>', {subjectid:subjectid},`

Comment: @Ae98 the checkbox value is $('checkbox').val(); you can pass it as you want, also from url you post

Comment: you can try **$.post('<?php echo site_url('academic/ajax_get_subject_credit'); ?>', {subjectid:subjectid,checkbox:$('checkbox').val()},**